# Problem with student badge

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges

When I look at the list of [people having gained the 'Student' badge](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/badges/2/student), the list is full of unavailable questions, from July 7th onwards on page 2.

- jul 7 at 6:37 (post deleted or otherwise unavailable) — [John Wordsworth](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/2266/john-wordsworth) 1133
- jul 6 at 22:38 [How to calculate the vector of an interception?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/14546/how-to-calculate-the-vector-of-an-interception) — [NobbZ](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/8405/nobbz) 266

The same bug occurs in StackOverflow, from page [205](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/2?page=205) onwards (at time of edit).

- jul 7 at 2:49 (post deleted or otherwise unavailable) — [Keval Prabhu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/735631/keval-prabhu) 62
- jul 7 at 2:24 IE9 - [HTML5 MP4 playback problem: Weird color difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6451283/ie9-html5-mp4-playback-problem-weird-color-difference) — [Laust Deleuran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/799327/laust-deleuran) 465

It seems that something happened between 2:49 and 2:24 on july the 7th...

Comment: Have you tried reporting this to Meta Stack Overflow? It would surely get more publicity there. Though hopefully it will still be seen by the Stack Exchange employees here.

Comment: They do cross site checks on the bug and feature request tags so it's very likely that they will see this.

Comment: @Noctrine♦ Seems like it hasn't been picked up, any way of transferring this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Viewing badges, I see "post deleted or otherwise unavailable"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100725/viewing-badges-i-see-post-deleted-or-otherwise-unavailable)

Comment: @Cody Gray It's not a duplicate, because for one I asked first (xD) and because the other issue is now solved, but not this one.

Comment: @Jonathan: Yeah, I was aware of the dates, but since that one had gotten some attention and seemed to be resolved, this was the one I suggested as the duplicate. It was nothing personal. My real question was the second one you answered: has this issue been resolved? I figured they were related, and you just hadn't been back to check since. If that's not the case, ignore the close vote.

Comment: I raised the other one, and confirm it has been fixed. Jonathan raised this one before me, and I confirm (by following the link) his has not been fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We found a very subtle bug in the student badge.  We'll correct the badge reasons after the next deployment.

*Update:* The fix is deployed and all possible reasons have been synced up.