# Viewing badges, I see "post deleted or otherwise unavailable"

Tags: bug, status-completed

I got some new badges. I went to [see for which answers](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer?userid=23).

[image]

Oh no, have I annoyed another moderator, and had all my answers deleted? Nope. They are still all around - but I will try to be be nicer to them just in case. :-)

Comment: Looks alright to me. Did it fix itself?

Comment: @TimStone, it is indeed fixed, and *I* didn't fix it. I don't want to say it fixed itself, because for all I know some hard-working developer just rolled out a new release, just for me. :-)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100634/problem-with-student-badge

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is another bug that was fixed tonight - thanks for pointing it out.