# What can make a post 'otherwise unavailable' in a badge question list?

Tags: support, badges, reversal-badge

(this doesn't appear to be a dupe of [Viewing badges, I see “post deleted or otherwise unavailable”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100725/viewing-badges-i-see-post-deleted-or-otherwise-unavailable) or [Problem with student badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100634/problem-with-student-badge), which appear to have been specific localised bugs)

---

Viewing [the older end of the list of Reversal badge awards on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/95?page=2), we see that a number of the awards have

> (post deleted or otherwise unavailable)

where the link to the answer should be. Now, where a post has been subject to a 'normal' deletion (as with the oldest link on the list, [What is your most used .NET namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602152/what-is-your-most-used-net-namespace/602170#602170) (10k only)), the text is there and the link still works.

So 'normal' deletion doesn't account for these missing links. What does?

Comment: It could be that those posts were amongst the very few that were hard deleted, either intentionally or accidentally.